# Determine page size (in bytes) of provided url in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, curl, wget

I have a rails app. And it is storing urls of various pages. Now I want to get the size of those pages (along with js, css and images those pages has). What is the best way to do that?
I tried to curl or wget the page and finding the content-length header information, but I guess content length does not gives the page size (its just the body length of http response).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda overkill, but you can use Nokogiri (https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/), at least to get the number of characters in the body tag...

```
doc = Nokogiri.parse(open('http://example.com'))
body = doc.search('body').first
body.content.length
```